Cannot Push Log Data to Azure EventHub From Azure AKS using OpenTelemetry
I have an Azure AKS cluster and I am trying to send my container level logs to an Azure EventHub using OpenTelemetry Collector. I am deploying the OpenTelemetry Collector as a DaemonSet and below is the YAML configuration for the exporter configuration.
exporters:
  kafka/event-hub-application-dead-messages-eh:
    brokers:
      - dev-application-ehns.servicebus.windows.net:9093
    topic: "application-dead-messages-eh"
    auth:
      plain_text:
        username: "Endpoint=sb://dev-application-ehns.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=n5sadAfjkb7/sad+asdjb/sadsadSADSAdasdk="
        password: "Endpoint=sb://dev-application-ehns.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=n5sadAfjkb7/sad+asdjb/sadsadSADSAdasdk="

Considering the fact that Azure EventHub is a Kafka wrapper, I had decided to use the Kafka OpenTelemetry exporter.
However, once the OTEL collector is deployed to the AKS cluster, I am getting the below error:

Error: cannot start pipelines: kafka: client has run out of available brokers to talk to: EOF; failed to shutdown pipelines: no existing monitoring routine is running; no existing monitoring routine is running; no existing monitoring routine is running


2024/06/25 20:32:57 collector server run finished with error: cannot start pipelines: kafka: client has run out of available brokers to talk to: EOF; failed to shutdown pipelines: no existing monitoring routine is running; no existing monitoring routine is running; no existing monitoring routine is running

kubectl exec -it -n dev test-app -- curl -v telnet://dev-application-ehns.servicebus.windows.net:9093

 * Rebuilt URL to: telnet://dev-application-ehns.servicebus.windows.net:9093/
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 10.123.9.15...
 * TCP_NODELAY set
 * Connected to dev-application-ehns.servicebus.windows.net:9093 (10.123.9.15) port 9093 (#0)

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:03 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:04 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:05 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:06 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:07 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:08 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:09 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:10 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:11 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:12 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:13 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:14 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:15 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:16 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:17 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:18 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:19 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:20 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:21 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:22 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:23 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:24 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:25 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:26 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:27 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:28 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:29 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:30 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:31 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:32 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:33 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:34 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:35 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:36 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:37 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:38 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:39 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:40 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:41 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:42 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:43 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:44 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:45 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:46 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:47 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:48 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:49 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:50 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:51 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:52 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:53 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:54 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:55 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:56 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:57 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:58 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:59 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:59 --:--:--     0
 * Closing connection 0

I tried to curl to the Azure EventHub from a pod in the Azure AKS cluster.It says that Connected to dev-application-ehns.servicebus.windows.net:9093 it's connected. Therefore, I am wondering whether this is a network connectivity restriction or a configuration problem from the OTEL collector end.
My intention is to send the Azure AKS logs to Azure EventHub using OpenTelemetry.
Does anyone know how to fix this issue?
